# Tomcat configuration help: multiple ports not responding

Tags: tomcat, configuration, ports, railo

My goal is to have port 80 and 81 listen and serve content from two distinct paths. I'm looking at replicating what I used to do with IIS and creating websites on specific ports.

I took the base configuration file and added the following lines inside the Server tag (server.xml):

```
<Service name="stable">
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
    <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\stable\" />
  </Service>
  <Service name="release">
    <Connector port="81" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
    <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\release\" />
  </Service>
```

I was going on a tip where I had to install a Service tag with Connector and Context tag for each port I wanted to run (inside the main Server tag).

I looked at my log and found the following:

```
16-Jan-2011 8:54:44 AM org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter service
SEVERE: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am aware about the Context working better in a the more localized context.xml file, but I don't mind restarting until I get this working. Or maybe it NEEDS to be there (not per APress Pro Apache TomCat6).

At this point, going to IP:80 doesn't bring up nothing, no file, no error, just a blank page. Even when I try to access index.html (that was copied in the proper docBase), I get a blank screen without any errors.

**Edit #2**

I figured I'd post my files in case someone had more time on their hands and wanted a go at them.

Here's my server.xml file:
http://pastebin.com/DAunTPTg

Here's the error I'm getting at the moment:
http://pastebin.com/mrrd0116

**Edit #3**

To make things simpler, I've tried to have port 80 respond properly.

As per my book:

> The name of this virtual host, as
>   configured with DNS. One of the
>   hosts nested within an engine  must
>   have a name that matches the
>   defaultHost attribute of that engine.

Why would I be indicating anything but localhost (localhost1 wouldn't work would it?)

This is where I am at now, still not working:

```
<Service name="Stable">
        <Connector 
            port="80" 
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"                
            connectionTimeout="20000" />

        <Engine name="Stable" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host 
                name="localhost"  
                appBase="webapps">

                <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\stable" />               
            </Host>
        </Engine>
  </Service>
```

I'm also getting a new errors:

> 18-Jan-2011 8:37:12 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
>   start SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
>   LifecycleException:  Error
>   initializaing : 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4380)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

and

> 18-Jan-2011 8:36:47 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener
>   createMBeans SEVERE: createMBeans:
>   Throwable
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createMBean(MBeanUtils.java:504)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:570)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:535)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:498)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:656)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:628)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.createMBeans(ServerLifecycleListener.java:278)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerLifecycleListener.java:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:703)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

**Edit #4**

I added the folder structure /Stable/localhost under the conf folder. Also added both host-manager.xml and manager.xml.

Still doesn't work.

**Edit #5**

I think I got it, well, I'm serving html and cfml pages with some errors in the log files.

```
<Service name="Stable">
        <Connector 
            port="80" 
            protocol="HTTP/1.1"                
            connectionTimeout="20000" />

        <Engine name="Stable" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host 
                name="localhost"  
                appBase="C:\websites\test\stable\">

                <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\stable\" path="" />              
            </Host>
        </Engine>
  </Service>
```

Errors:

> 18-Jan-2011 11:31:40 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   resourcesStart SEVERE: Error starting
>   static Resources
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Document base
>   C:\websites\test\stable\manager does
>   not exist or is not a readable
>   directory»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
<Service name="Stable">
    <Connector 
        port="80" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"                
        connectionTimeout="20000" />

    <Engine name="Stable" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host 
            name="localhost"  
            appBase="C:\websites\test\stable\">

            <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\stable\" path="" />              
        </Host>
    </Engine>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track, but you're just missing some of the child elements that are listed in the specification for the Service element.

I think you're just forgetting the **Engine** and **Host** elements, which are grandparent  and parent respectively to the **Context** element.

```xml
<Service name="stable">
    <Connector port              ="80"
               protocol          ="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads        ="150"
               connectionTimeout ="20000"/>
               
    <Engine name        ="stable"
            defaultHost ="localhost">
            
        <Host name    ="localhost1"
              appBase ="webapp1">
              
            <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\stable\"/>
            
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

```xml
<Service name="release">
    <Connector port              ="81"
               protocol          ="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads        ="150"
               connectionTimeout ="20000"/>
               
    <Engine name        ="release"
            defaultHost ="localhost2">
            
        <Host name    ="localhost2"
              appBase ="webapp2">
              
            <Context docBase="C:\websites\test\release\"/>
            
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

For more information and a more detailed example, which defines two Service elements, one on port 8080 and one on port 9080, see this mailing list post:

http://www.mail-archive.com/users@tomcat.apache.org/msg44729.html

Comment: @jmort252: thanks! So far, I'm getting a different error. Will try to debug and post if I can't get it working. I will also checkout the link you posted.