# Running specific webapp on alternative port in Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run different apps on single Tomcat instance behind different ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)

Is there a way to configure Tomcat 7 to host specific web application on alternative port?

I am aware that I can change port for connector in conf/sever.xml, but this changes listening port globally, for all webapps deployed in tomcat instance.

I cannot use transparent proxy or any other intermediate gateway to redirect request, I need to solve this using minimum additional infrastructure dependencies, so if there is a way to do this only by configuring tomcat I'd be really happy.

For example: I want webapp_1 to be accessible only from {topmcat_host}:{port1} and webapp_2 only from {topmcat_host}:{port2}

Thanks.

Comment: This might help: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports Also found some info: - http://www.coderanch.com/t/556239/Tomcat/Multiple-webapps-different-ports - http://www.coderanch.com/t/87406/Tomcat/Different-webapps-same-instance-tomcat

Answer (score 0):

There is no *configurable* way to make Tomcat listen on a requested port in terms of application settings. The most *civilized* option is, of course, configure all ports in `server.xml` and switch as necessary.

If you can't do the above, you can write a servlet listener which binds on an arbitrary port and forwards all requests/responsed to/from the "main" port (you can also add request validation only to allow requests for this app). But this is an insane solution.