# Is it possible to host one webapp on 1 port and another webapp on another port in Apache tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I have 2 webapps in jsp, one of them is for public use, and the other is for local use.

Is it possible to host one webapp on 1 port and another webapp on another port in Apache tomcat?
I see the appBase in the connecter in server.xml file, what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

You should look more on stackoverflow.

I have found this, it might help you

[How to run different apps on single Tomcat instance behind different ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)