# Is it possible to have same tomcat run on two or many different ports?

Tags: java, tomcat

Can a single instance of tomcat run on two different ports. For example say I have one and only one tomcat running, then can I type localhost:8080 & localhost:8181 in browser & got it working?

If yes, please let me know the procedure.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can find more info on Google and SO.. :)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be an additional webserver like an apache which redirects to the tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your server.xml to create additional connector elements:

```
<Connector port="8081"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
debug="0" connectionTimeout="20000"
disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

For example.

I might be inclined to address this via NAT or a load balancer however.