# cant we deploy multiple spring boot application on aws server under tomcat?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have 3 spring boot application and  want to deploy all on single EC2  instance.

When i have tried to deploy war and deploy under tomcat/webapps some applications will not work as embedded tomcat in  spring boot uses port 8080 and other web applications which are exists in tomcat stopped working.

Other options i have tried is changing server.port in application.properties file running jar with java -jar app.jar.

This works but for only one app if i want to run one app and if i press cntrl+c or cntrl+z or closing terminal(closing ssh connection) is stopping application.

When found during my search  that we can do with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.but i have already created one free tier ec2 instance is there any way to make it work with out changing instance.

can some one help me out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your app using  `java -jar app.jar` add `&` to the end allowing the process to run in the background.

Using the command `java -jar app.jar &` you can run multiple apps in the background. This will return a pid "Process ID"

You can use this pid to kill the app later with `kill -9 <pid>`

To check running processes you can use `ps aux | grep java` (We are searching for anything that contains "java")

For running multiple wars on tomcat explicitly [deploying multiple applications to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569327/deploying-multiple-applications-to-tomcat)

Comment: and one more question if i want to run with different ports like 8082 and 8085 etc should i add custom TCP rule in inbound address of aws console ?

Comment: Yes but be careful not to expose ports to the outside world if you don't have any security enabled.