# Multiple spring boot application in a single tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, web-applications

Is there any way to deploy multiple spring boot web application in a single external tomcat server and distinguish by different context path but port name will be same like 8080?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23570816/13070 What you describe is exactly how deploying multiple .war files in Tomcat works. Are you running into an issue when you try that?