# Run different webapps in tomcat on differnet ports

Tags: java, tomcat, port, restlet, configure

I have a REST web application that is running in Tomcat. I can access this RESTful service with `http://localhost:8080/MyApplication/Myresource`.

How can I configure Tomcat so that this webapp runs on a different port while other webapps continue to run on port 8080 or on another port?  Specifically, I want to access

```
http://localhost:XXXX/MyApplication/Myresource
```

and

```
http://localhost:YYYY/OtherApplication/Resource
```

Comment: Similar Question[Changing Tomcat Http Port][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756039/how-to-change-the-port-of-tomcat-from-8080-to-80

Answer (score 1):

**ITS SIMPLE , JUST SEE THIS IMAGE**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `server.xml` file inside the `conf` dir, there's the http connector definition:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Change the `8080` value to whatever else you need and restart tomcat.

If you want to have some apps run on one port and other apps on another port, then you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)

Comment: but in this case i have all application in tomcat on port XXXX that i set in connector?! If i want two application with http://localhost:XXXX/MyApplication/Myresource and http://localhost:YYYY/MyApplication2/Myresource ? Thanks

Comment: @gpiscite In that case, have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)

Comment: Thanks @Aleks G . So It is impossibile to have each application with its door in one TomCat Instance? I got it right? Thanks in advances.

Comment: @gpiscite Yes, it it possible, but you have to specify this in the tomcat config file - you cannot specify this inside your apps.

Comment: okkey! thanks . I read a post linked. So I can have two application with two different port but i lose the gerarchy. I can have localhost:XXXX/Myresource and localhost:YYYY/Myresource, but no localhost:XXXX/MyApplication/Myresource and localhost:YYYY/MyApplication2/Myresource ?!