# How to start/stop an application from a webapplication running both on same tomcat

Tags: java, linux, bash, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

I need some help: I have two .war files running on tomcat 7, one is a webapplication, the other one is just a "normal" java application. Now I want to figure out how to start/stop the application from my webapplication. Both applications are on the same tomcat. Operation system is Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can configure that in your `server.xml` file and put 2 services :

```
<Service name="app1">
   <Connector port="8081" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
<Service name="app2">
   <Connector port="8082" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" />
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="app2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
      </Host>
   </Engine>
</Service>
```

Then the application will run on

1. app1 on http://localhost:8081
2. app2 on http://localhost:8082

### Resource Link:

1. [Listen Multiple Ports in Tomcat](http://www.coderanch.com/t/84172/Tomcat/listen-multiple-ports)
2. [How to run different apps on single Tomcat instance behind different ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)