# Two different projects on single server and single domain

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat, mod-jk

Suppose I have a domain `www.example.com` and the project is hosted in  *tomcat/linux/apache_server*

Say  `www.example.com` is fetching the file from */tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/proejct_folder*

Now, what I want to do is `www.example.com/cms` or `cms.example.com` to redirect to different project folder. Which is hosted in same webapss folder like 
*/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.63/webapps/cms_proejct_folder*

How can I do that in linux? What I need to do?
Any help please

Comment: Please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37807742/2293534

Comment: my problem is different i want to host the file on same port and same domain but can access it through different url