# How can we separate management port from application port

Tags: tomcat

There is a requirement to have my managment port different then my application port.

My management port should be let's say 8083 and when I deploy my application and try to access it , it should run on a separate port let's say 7777.

How can this be achieved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run different apps on single Tomcat instance behind different ports?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823290/how-to-run-different-apps-on-single-tomcat-instance-behind-different-ports)

Comment: requirement is a bit different as i want to deploy on mangement port but those deployed apps must be accessible from another port instead of management port.