# Can I host a webapp on tomcat and listen to a different SOAP port?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis

Suppose I have a webapp that deployed on tomcat 80 port.

Is it possible to make this webapp to listen on a different SOAP port say 8080. So other app can send SOAP request to 8080 instead of 80?

By the way I am using axis

Comment: Check this out, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719616/tomcat-configuration-help-multiple-ports-not-responding

Comment: This link is all you need http://kief.com/running-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server.html

Comment: @dinukadev No I don't want to use two tomcat. I want the webapp running in one tomcat and listening to another port

Comment: You have not read the article. Its not two tomcat instances. One tomcat instance, two different configurations to run applications on two different ports.

Comment: @dinukadev I already know this long time ago. This is not what I want.  I want to have one webapp, and server for two SOAP ports. These two SOAP have different APIs